# Debian 11 security updates: deb or security, which to choose?

Tags: debian, security, upgrade

I'm in the process of upgrading my first system to Debian 11 / Bullseye following Debian's [41-point-plan](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html). The sources.list entry for security updates has changed and according to [the documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#security-archive) it should point to the server deb.debian.org. On Debian 10 and a fresh install of Bullseye it points to security.debian.org. These are actually different servers, with deb returning a single IP and security 4 IPs.

Am I correct in assuming that deb.debian.org uses some kind of anycasting / loadbalancing and would be the better choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm too impatient and should have read the documentation all the way through before posting. Further down it says

> On new installations the default is for APT to be set up to use the
> Debian APT CDN service

which answers the question.

Comment: So it means `deb.debian.org` and not `security.debian.org`, right?

Comment: @bolino: That seems to be correct.